# Why is this css selector not working?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have the following code (generated by Drupal; I have no control over it.)

```
<div class="spacer">
    <div class="region region-home-ad-banner">
        <div id="block-views-banner-ad-block-block" class="block block-views  contextual-links-region">
            <div class="contextual-links-wrapper">
                <ul class="contextual-links">
                    <li class="views-ui-edit first">
                        <a href="/banner_ad_block/edit/block?destination=node">Edit view</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="block-configure last">
                        <a href="/banner_ad_block-block/configure?destination=node">Configure block</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div> <!-- end contextual-links-wrapper -->

            <div class="content">
                <div class="view view-banner-ad-block view-id-banner_ad_block view-display-id-block view-dom-id-542147d83a500d1c31244e2e2a583562">
                    <div class="view-content">
                      <div class="views-row views-row-1 views-row-odd views-row-first views-row-last">
                        <div class="views-field views-field-field-ad-image">
                            <div class="field-content">
                                <a href="http://www.externallink.com" target="_blank">
                                    <img src="expo-home-page-banner.jpg" width="912" height="100" alt="" />
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div> <!-- end content -->
        </div> <!-- end block-views-banner-ad-block-block -->
    </div> <!-- end region-home-ad-banner -->
</div> <!-- end spacer -->
```

I have this css that works:

```
.spacer img{
    background: #ffffff;
    border:5px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    padding-top: 30px; 
    padding-bottom: 20px; 
}
```

I need to apply a background style to the div with the class "region-home-ad-banner", so I tried this:

```
.spacer>div.region-home-ad-banner {
    background: #ffffff;
}
```

According to Firebug, that selector isn't being applied at all. It's not being overwritten by something with higher priority, it just isn't happening at all.

Why would `.spacer img` find what it needs to, even though the img tag is buried in multiple levels, but `.spacer>div.region-home-ad-banner` isn't finding the div that's the immediate child of `.spacer`?

**EDITED TO ADD SCREENSHOT**

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you don't have a typo or something somewhere? http://jsfiddle.net/cLzGa/ -- what version of FFX?

Comment: I'm having no issues - it works fine in Chrome 20 and FF 15

Comment: There's no typos, and it's not working.

Comment: @EmmyS Try to find what's different on your actual code versus the code you posted. It's supposed to work, as the jsfiddle linked by Explosion Pills demonstrates. There must be something else on your code interfering. Maybe a CSS syntax error somewhere?

Comment: I'm posting a screenshot in the OP showing what Firebug does. There IS no difference in my actual code vs. what I posted; I copied my code and pasted it here.

Comment: are you sure it is not a caching problem? open the CSS tab in firebug, choose the CSS file, and make sure that rule is available in your CSS

Comment: http://tinkerbin.com/xEEsqyO0 works fine

Comment: Urg... it was caching, even though I'd cleared the server cache and the Drupal cache numerous times. Thanks, @Dan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be due to several reasons:

**Caching:**

Open the CSS tab in firebug, choose the CSS file, and make sure that rule is available in your CSS.
In that case, clear your cache (sometimes <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd> are not enough) and retry.

**Typo:**

Make sure you don't have any typo errors, open the console in firebug and check for warnings. Or open the `Error Console` in Firefox. (Tools--> Web Developer --> Error Console)
It can be a typo from a previous rule, for example, forgetting to put a closing curly bracket (`}`) will break your following rules.

Answer (score 0):

From the structure of the HTML generated by drupal and the fairly unique class you are trying to use it looks like you don't need the direct descendant selector ">" and could try not using it:

```
.spacer div.region-home-ad-banner {
    background: #ffffff;
}
```

However I see no reason why that selector should not work.